# Aegir tasks not running, after accidentally upgrading drush

Tags: drush, aegir

I have a BOA installation where I accidentally run the command drush self-update. This overrided the aegir-comparible drush with a newer version. When I realized the issue, two days later, I replaced the new drush with old one (4.6-dev), found in the backups.
The issue I am facing is that the tasks in the Aegir queue have stopped running. They give the message that they should run in the next cron, in about a minute, but then nothing happens. It keeps telling me that the last cron was run two days ago.

I have tried sudoing as Aegir and running the following:

drush vdel hosting_queue_cron_running -y
in case a semaphore is left, but this gives the message hosting_queue_cron_running not found.

/var/aegir/drush/drush.php '@hostmaster' hosting-dispatch --debug
and it runs fine, which means that the drush kicks the cron, but for some reason it doesn't reach Aegir

I tried to run barracuda up-stable in order to recover .drush, but it didn't recover it. I also tried to clean cache and rebuild registry. The time of the server is correct. Could you suggest some way to further debug the issue?

Comment: Your log shows the system cron starting hosting-dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem occurred due to [incomplete barracuda + octopus upgrade](https://drupal.org/node/2238261). One has to run the following commands to finish update

```
 barracuda up-stable
 octopus up-stable all
```